# Change gitlab CI/CD exit code

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm using docker to run a program as part of the CI/CD process.
at the program, if the exit code is 2 I don't want the CI/CD to fail and only get a warning.

added this to the gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
  allow_failure:
    exit_codes: 
      - 2
```

but even tho the docker exit code is (2) at the pipeline I'm getting `ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

How can I change the error code of the pipeline to be like as the docker error code?

Thanks.

Comment: If it says `Job failed: exit code 1` then the exit code is `1` not `2`. You must be mistaken about this. Note that the `docker run` command doesn't necessarily exit with the same exit code that that _container_ exits with.

Comment: I tested it locally  (docker run and then echo $?) and I'm getting "2"

Comment: I stand corrected, seems like it should do what you expect, then. Maybe try echoing the exit code in the pipeline to debug it. Your YAML definition for `allow_failure` seems correct.

Comment: I tried to do it, it doesn't get there. (after the exit from the docker the pipeline stop and failed)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having a similar issue. Gitlab is reporting exit code 1 rather than the specific exit code of the tool I'm using : https://commitizen-tools.github.io/commitizen/

Comment: I didn't find buy didn't need it anymore, ty for the tool @brettc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `allow_failure` keyword, your job is allowed to fail. It means that it won't failed if the specified exit_code resulted.

Your job will still have an exit code, but it will be marked in `warning` in your pipeline instead of `failed`

As an example, I made a simple job :

```yaml
stages:
    - test

test_error_code:
    stage: test
    image: alpine:3.15.4
    script:
        - echo "bienvenuto"
        - exit 2
    allow_failure:
        exit_codes: 2
```

After adding the last two line, the pipeline moved to status `warning` :
[See pipeline picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGig8.png)

Hope it helps you!

You can find more information here : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure

Comment: Ty, with ur code it does work. but my code looks like this:

  script:
      - docker build . -t test
      - docker run test

i'f I'm trying to add things after the docker run its doesn't get there (the job exit with exit code 1) 
my docker there is a python code with an exit(2) call